# Read and Save list of numbers as numbers in txt files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

I have lists of float numbers in python.
I would like to save some lists in txt files and I read them list by list as they are. But after I wrote the following code I discovered that str(i)convert every digit in one str. I can not read them as well as they are written.
Ps I have 10,000 list of result so I would like to save every list in one line .

```
result = [-0.33434,0.4434, 4343....]
with open("out.txt", w) as out:
  for i in result:
      out.write(str(i)+' ')
 out.write("\n")
```

Comment: I do not understand what "str(i)convert every digit in one str" means. Can you give an example of a float, how it's converted to `str` and how you want it to be converted to `str`? Because if you need to read the file you're generating in this code, then `with open("out.txt") as inp: numbers = [[float(word) for word in line.split()] for line in inp]` should work.

Comment: Yes , because when I do out.write(i) is says i should be string to be written inside the file

Comment: @Boris The code that I written is not working well for  save the lists , so I  need to fix it to save every list called result in txt file and read them list by list

Comment: You need to make a few fixes to your code: fix up the indentation, the last line should start with 2 spaces (not one, so that it matches the  `for i in result:` line above) and `open("out.txt", w)` should be `open("out.txt", "w")` with the `w` in quotes `"w"`), and then it works for me, I get a file with 1 line that has a bunch of numbers on it. Or do you want each number to be on its own line? then change the second last line to be `out.write(str(i)+'\n')`.

Comment: @Boris I need the whole list to be written in one line, When I use the code that I wrote to save in the file , when I read it , it consider every digit as single item of the list. because str(i) consider every digit is one str. I hope it is clear

Comment: Then show your code for reading the file, that's where the issue is. Or try using the code I wrote in my first comment to read it.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

For multiple lists, put them all inside a single list and write that to the pkl/txt file.

```py
import pickle
import numpy as np

results = [
    [1.456,2.245,-3.441], 
    [4.53, 4.55, 1.22]
]

np.savetxt("results.txt", results)   # write

#read
result = np.loadtxt("results.txt")
print(result.tolist())
```

If you want to have names associated to your lists, consider using a `dict`. But then, you can only use `pickle`.

```py
import pickle

results = {
    "result1": [1.456,2.245,-3.441], 
    "result2": [4.53, 4.55, 1.22],
}

# write
with open("results.pkl", "wb") as resultFile:
    pickle.dump(results, resultFile)
    
# read
with open("results.pkl", "rb") as resultFile:
    result = pickle.load(resultFile)
    print(result)
```

---

### Original Answer

Use `pickle` or `numpy` for this, as that is more well suited for this task.

Using `pickle`:

```py
import pickle

result1 = [1.456,2.245,-3.441]

# write
with open("result1.pkl", "wb") as resultFile:
    pickle.dump(x, resultFile)

# read
with open("result1.pkl", "rb") as resultFile:
    result = pickle.load(resultFile)
    print(result)
```

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

result1 = [1.456,2.245,-3.441]

np.savetxt("result1.txt", result1)   # write

#read
result = np.loadtxt("result1.txt")
print(result.tolist())
```

Comment: This is code to save only one list and read one list, How i can save multi  lists and read them either in pickle or numpy

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library to do this, you can simply [`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) each list by a known separator and then write the resulting string to the file.

Here, I assume you have a list-of-lists called `allResults`, which is of the form

```python
allResults = [
       [-0.332,434,0.4434,4865],
       [9.456,-0.540,-7.06540,5.05453],
       # ... and so on
    ]

separator = "," 

with open("out.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for l in allResults:
        out_string = separator.join(str(x) for x in l) + "\n"
        out_file.write(out_string)
```

Now, `out.txt` contains:

```
-0.332,434,0.4434,4865
9.456,-0.54,-7.0654,5.05453
```

Then to read the file, you can read each line, split it by your separator, convert each element of the split string to a float, and put that new list in your list of lists:

```python
all_lists = []
with open("out.txt", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        new_list = [float(x) for x in line.split(separator)]
        all_lists.append(new_list)
```

And now you have your list of lists back:

```
all_lists: [[-0.332, 434.0, 0.4434, 4865.0], [9.456, -0.54, -7.0654, 5.05453]]
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to read it again, read the line and split it on ' '(space). This should give you the string representation of the float numbers. afterwards you can use the float(num) method to convert it back to a number